# var is deprecated / var is used in solidity documentations / removing var is throwing compile errors

Tags: solidity

From Solidity tutorials:

```
contract C {
    uint[] counters;
    function getCounter(uint index)
        returns (uint counter, bool error) {
            if (index >= counters.length) return (0, true);
            else return (counters[index], false);
        }
    function checkCounter(uint index) {
        var (counter, error) = getCounter(index);
        if (error) { ... }
        else { ... }
    }
}
```

If I compile this with truffle, a warning is displayed:

> Warning: Use of the "var" keyword is deprecated.

What is ther alternate to removing var when receiving tupples from returning functions? I tried removing var but truffle refuses from compiling with error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define the variable first with their type and then assign to the tuple.

```
function checkCounter(uint index) {
    uint counter;
    bool error;
    (counter, error) = getCounter(index);
    if (error) {  }
    else {  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Variables have to be strictly typed now. So you have to declare the variables first:

```
contract C {
    uint[] counters;
    function getCounter(uint index)
        returns (uint counter, bool error) {
            if (index >= counters.length) return (0, true);
            else return (counters[index], false);
        }
    function checkCounter(uint index) {
        uint counter;
        bool error;

        (counter, error) = getCounter(index);
        if (error) { ... }
        else { ... }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// You have only to use solidity syntax, you can'nt mixed with javascript syntax
// 'var' is not accepted 

contract Counters {

  uint[] counters;

  function _getCounter(uint _index) view private returns (uint, bool success) {
    require(_index >= 0 && _index < counters.length);
    return (counters[_index], true); // Return the value on that position in the array
  }

  function checkCounter(uint _index) view public returns ( ... ) {
    uint counter;
    bool success;
    (counter, success) = _getCounter(_index);
    if (success == false) { ... } else { ... };
  }

}
```

Comment: var was accepted in previous versions of solidity

Comment: var was legit in the previous versions and still used in the documentation as reference. Its not javascript syntax http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/control-structures.html?highlight=var#destructuring-assignments-and-returning-multiple-values . now is deprecated but the code will still compile with warnings