# I have deployed my smart contract but i am unable to interact with it using truffle

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, truffle-migration

MY ChainList.sol code

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract ChainList  {

  struct  data  {
    uint   ownernumber;
    uint   id;
  }

  uint value;
  mapping (uint256 => data) public  datamatching;

  function storedata (uint _ownernumber, uint _id) public {
    var  persondata  = datamatching[value];
    persondata .ownernumber = _ownernumber;
    persondata. id  =  _id;
  }

  function getData(uint256 userId) returns (uint, uint){
    return (datamatching[userId].ownernumber, datamatching[userId].id);
  }
}
```

// deploying  contract in using migrations

```
var ChainList = artifacts.require("./Migrations.sol");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(ChainList);
}
```

// My trufle.js code

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }
  }
};
```

i am have deployed succefully

```
Compiling ./contracts/ChainList.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol...

Compilation warnings encountered:

/

home/mdvenkatesh/Desktop/asset/contracts/ChainList.sol:14:5: Warning: Use of the "var" keyword is deprecated.
    var  persondata  = datamatching[value];
    ^-------------^
,/home/mdvenkatesh/Desktop/asset/contracts/Migrations.sol:11:3: Warning: Defining constructors as functions with the same name as the contract is deprecated. Use "constructor(...) { ... }" instead.

**Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
  ... 0x942947d411cc40c214ee717f12a8626033aea99b9db0cfda2189a8c214c0d068
  Migrations: 0x4d838fd69456fcb2c4c49b1b05c8ae7b7205cde5
Saving successful migration to network...
  ... 0x20659b7fdf1ac7c4a1899be68938297b5fb1cae318024c61eee7886d007d134d
Saving artifacts...
Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
  Replacing Migrations...
  ... 0xe287e9ccbe891349ca0a2b1bac64a1291558b3817a6689431bf88721122eb7c1
  Migrations: 0xcc3979c6af9f5003445f26e5c1dfdc140bba29c5
Saving successful migration to network...
  ... 0x2a3b60f8cf3571ef12bb81ea5c80d22b6e2febae8e38f2dd0c05e0f147137305
Saving artifacts...**
```

Now I  am trying to  intract with truffle i am getting the following error

**ChainList.deployed().then(function(instance){app= instance });**

```
Error: ChainList has not been deployed to detected network (network/artifact mismatch)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-contract/contract.js:454:1
```

I Think I followed all steps but i don't know what  went wrong please help me

Comment: did you configure truffle to use your network, I mean in your JS code. 
can you add your entire js code or a gist link ?

Comment: Check this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/45559/var-is-deprecated-var-is-used-in-solidity-documentations-removing-var-is-thr and first fix the **var** error and try again. Also note that the constructor is defined differently now. Fix these first and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have messed up your deployment scripts. In the end you should have 2 files in your `/migrations/` folder:

1. `1_initial_migration.js`

   ```
   var Migrations = artifacts.require("./Migrations.sol");

   module.exports = function(deployer) {
     deployer.deploy(Migrations);
   };
   ```
2. `2_deploy_contracts.js`

   ```
   var ChainList = artifacts.require("/path/to/ChainList.sol");

   module.exports = function (deployer) {
       deployer.deploy(ChainList);
   }
   ```

In your example, you changed the migration variables to "ChainList", but you still point to `./Migrations.sol`. Simply change this to point to your contract file instead.

Comment: Thanks ,
I have deployed  successfully  my contract but my function is not working as I expected i taught get function will give all the ids of my parent but it is not happining plese help me to create a function which gets all the id's that are linked to my  parent id

Comment: You should open a new question with clear examples of what you expect for a given input and output.